# How to include html files in a jar?

Tags: java, html, http, azure, jar

So, the question is rather simple, and might be supid.

I have created a simple webserver, for which i need to deploy to a Azure, virtual machine.
I have created a jar file, and a bat file to start the server on the file.

In my creation of the webserver, i have a filehandler, and some html pages.

Is there any way to include the html pages in the final jar file for deployment ?

Comment: Move all your HTML files as resources of your application under a resources folder.

Comment: alright, i have a folder named public and a file reference to that foler in my webserver. Should the folder just be named resouces? and where would i put the resources folder ? in the root of the project or?